# Create a backup of a document

Tags: vba, ms-word

My macro should make a backup (in a specified path) of a file that is currently being saved, a procedure that is often discussed since it is a feature that Word lacks.

```
Private Sub Document_Close()
Dim blank As Range
    For Each blank In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    If Len(blank.Text) = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Next
End Sub

Sub FileSave()
Dim BackupPath As String, objF As Object, retVal As Long, Rslt
BackupPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Documents\BackupWord\"
With ActiveDocument
  If .Path = "" Then: If Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
  If Len(Trim(.Range.Text)) = 1 Then Exit Sub
   .Save
  If Dir(BackupPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir BackupPath
    MsgBox "Backup folder has been created.", vbInformation
  End If
  If .Path & "\" = BackupPath Then
    MsgBox "WARNING! Backup folder is the same as the source folder", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Set objF = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  retVal = -1
  On Error Resume Next
  retVal = objF.CopyFile(.FullName, BackupPath & .Name, True)
  On Error GoTo 0
  Set objF = Nothing
  If retVal <> 0 Then MsgBox "Backup has not been copied to folder " BackupPath, vbExclamation
End With
End Sub
```

I will describe what the macro currently does.

1. FileSave procedure is intercepted.
2. The macro checks if an active document is saved. If it is, no extra action is required and the macro closes.
3. If an active document in not saved, the usual "Save As" dialogue appears. If the user chooses to not save the file then the macro closes.
4. If document is not saved, the macros saves it.
5. The macro looks for a backup folder. If it is not found, the macro creates it and shows a message box.
6. Then the macro checks if the source folder is the same as the backup folder. If they are the same, the macro shows a message and closes.
7. The active (current) document is copied to the backup folder. If it fails, a message box is displayed.

My macros fail to make a backup on two occasions.

1. When I open Word (no document opened, just blank page), modify it
   and choose to close Word, a SaveAs dialog is shown. Then I choose to
   save and the document is saved correctly but a backup copy is not
   created.
2. When a document exists on, say, harddrive, pendrive etc.
   and I will modify it and choose to close Word a SaveAs dialog is shown.
   Then I choose to save and the document is saved correctly but a
   backup copy is not created.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a class, i believe at addin level to track all sheets, something like...

```
Option Explicit

    Private WithEvents wd As Word.Application

    Public Sub initialise(w As Word.Application)
        Set wd = w
    End Sub

    Private Sub wd_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
           '   Your code here
    End Sub
```

In your addin (.dotm) file you'd have the following

```
Option Explicit
Public c As clsCustomWord

Sub AutoExec()
    Set c = New clsCustomWord
    c.initialise Application
End Sub
```

Hope this helps